# Присваивание первого елемента массива к последнему элементу второго массива

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Суть задачи состоит в том что есть два массива:
$array1 = ["1", "2", "3"] ; $array2 = ["3", "2", "1"].
Нужно записать значения в третий массив по указаному алгоритму:
1-ый элемент 2-го массива к 3-ему элементу 2-го массива, второй к второму, третий к первому.
Должно получится так: $result = ["1-1" , "2-2", "3-3"]

Comment: ну дак цикл в руки и вперед

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = ["1", "2", "3"] ; 
$array2 = ["3", "2", "1"];
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){
    return $a . '-' . $b;
}, $array1, array_reverse($array2));
```

**UPD** Пара вариантов с циклом. Подразумевается, что длина массивов одинакова

Вариант 1:

```
$array2 = array_reverse($array2);
$result = [];
foreach($array1 as $i => $v) {
    $result[] = $v . '-' . $array2[$i];
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
$result = [];
$total = count($array1);
for($i = 0, $k = $total - 1; $i < $total; $i++, $k--) {
    $result[] = $array1[$i] . '-' . $array2[$k];    
}
```

Последний вариант можно изменить, используя одну переменную для счётчика

```
$result = [];
$total = count($array1) - 1;
for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {
    $result[] = $array1[$i] . '-' . $array2[$total - $i];   
}
```

Comment: только начал изучение, не понимаю этой строчки, а конкретно что означають точки "return $a . '-' . $b;"

Comment: Точка в данном случае - это [оператор конкатенации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php) строк. Если простыми словами, то "склеивание" строк.

Comment: спасибо, а если решить эту задачу через цыкл то как оно должно выглядеть? а то не до конца понимаю что означает array_map и что оно делает

Comment: Добавил в ответе

Comment: @makson707 `array_map` используется для преобразования вида массивов, на вход получается один или более массивов, и с помощью переданной функции преобразует элементы. эта функция на вход получает по одному элеменету из каждого переданного массива. зы: конкатенация `$a . " - " . $b` будет работать несколько медленнее чем подстановка в сроку вида `"$a - $b"`, да и в целом последнее в большинстве случаев более читаемо. Функций для работы с массивами достаточно много, лучше с ними ознакомится.